# How do I find Vo in this circuit using superposition?

Tags: circuit-analysis, superposition

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMV3UA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have to find vo in this through superposition. I found the current using a test source of 1V like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFnyZk.png)</sup>

By doing so, with 1V as its test source, I used voltage divider to get the voltage of R2, so V2 = 1/7 Volts, by Ohms law, i2 = 28000A. By using it at the dependant source I got 61600 A.

How do I calculate the resistance of the circuit so I can use V=IR to get vo?

If you notice any mistake in my calculations, please point it out.

Comment: I am (maybe others as well) very curious to know how you calculated such humongous values of current.

Comment: @Mitu Raj Just a whole lot of miscalculations I guess, I first find the current of R2, using ohms law its current is I = V/R, But i think i multiplied it instead of dividing so thats what happened i guess. Totally my fault and just me being careless, not that it matters, i had the wrong approach in the first place

Answer (score 1):

At least you have found a way to avoid fast closing of the question as "doesn't bother to attempt anything" -case. By writing something random and obscure formally fulfills "he has tried something".

No ready to copy solution, but some guidance: In this case you should calculate  2 versions for Vo. Calculate the first version when source V1 replaced by a wire, the rest of the circuit must stay as is.

The second version of Vo must be calculated by simply wiping off source I1, the rest of the circuit must stay as is.

The final Vo is the sum of the 2 versions.

The education idea is that you must not change the controlled source I2 nor its sensing branch when finding partial solutions that should be combined. You will see also a question which demands "Use Thevenin's method!" and there's the same controlled source -trap.

Comment: I see my mistake now, can I ask, is removing all of the sources just use to find the equivalent resistance? And in cases like this, where voltage are being asked, I have to get rid of the sources one at a time?

Comment: and by the way, im sorry it looks "random and obscure" to you, but honestly, it was the way i thought off, so please excuse my inadequacy.

Comment: The whole resistance calculation is a non-understandable jumlble. You have used some fully unknown voltage divider formula in a case where's no voltage dividers and the calculation of 28000A from 1/7 volts and 4000 ohms has never seen Ohm's law. Sorry, but true. You must go back to the beginning - to a circuit which contains only a voltage source and a resistor. After mastering it you have a possibility to try more complex circuits such as a voltage source and 2 resistors. This all very likely can be sorted except in case you always get 1/7 when you divide 4 by 24.

Comment: @AedenSchmidt I think it is less confusing if you talk about **zeroing** a source rather than **removing** a source during superposition. A zeroed voltage source becomes a short circuit and a zeroed current source becomes an open circuit.